# Weird multicols problem

Tags: multicol

I have the following code with multicols and but the weird thing is that when I type in the multicols environment, it follows that the text automatically gets moved into the next column automatically when I would like for it to continue in the first column. My code is follows:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.22in,top=.22in,bottom=.22in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont
\begin{multicols}{3}


% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\section{Numerical Integration}
Midpoint: $(b-a)f(\frac{(a+b)}{2})$. Midpoint error is: $\frac{f''(\xi)}{24}(b-a)^{3}$ \\
Trapezoidal: $\frac{b-a}{2}[f(a)+f(b)]$. Trap error is: $ -\frac{f''(\xi)}{12}(b-a)^{3} $ \\
Simpson: $\frac{b-a}{6}[f(a)+4f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b)]$. \\ Simpson Error is $-\frac{f''''(\xi)}{90}(\frac{b-a}{2})^{5}$

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I am looking to save as much space as possible in the most organized way possible since I am looking to make a cheat sheet, which hence explains the small font size. Anyhow, when I compile the code, it follows that the 3rd line beginning with "simpson ..." gets moved into the 2nd column. How could I prevent this ?

Thank you

Comment: oops, typo mistake, but it still doesnt work so it is not that issue

Comment: It will balance the columns by default. If you add more stuff, doesn't the first column grow?

Comment: Yes you are right, when I added more stuff just now, it did get pushed into the first column. Didn't know that about multicol before

Comment: add \usepackage{lipsum} in the preamble and add the command \lipsum in the body that is next to simpson line and compile you will get all the formulae in the first column

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `multicols*` not`multicols`as an environment to suppress balancing (which is really the main purpose of the `multicol` package :-)